# Why my QuickSort using ForkJoin is so slow?

Tags: java, quicksort, fork-join

I have a simple program uses ForkJoin to accelerate QuickSort, but I found that the sort algorithm uses standard partition method is much faster than the one uses my partition methd.

If I don't use ForkJoin, the time performance of two partition method is almost the same. But I expect my partition method be faster.

---

Edit: **The compare is between standard partition() using ForkJoin and mypartition using ForkJoin**, so it doesn't relate with overheads of threading.

---

Edit:

When using standard partition method and 3 threads

```
sorted: true
total time: 3368
sorted: true
total time: 1578
```

When using my partition method and 3 threads

```
sorted: true
total time: 3587
sorted: true
total time: 2478
```

So the results shows that ForkJoin works well for standard partition method, but not well for my partition method.

---

```
package me.shu.lang.java.forkjoin;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class FJSort extends RecursiveAction {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6386324579247067081L;

    final int threshold = 32;

    final int[] data;
    final int lo;
    final int hi;

    public FJSort(int n)
    {
        this.data = new int[n];
        this.lo = 0;
        this.hi = n;

        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            this.data[i] = rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }

    public FJSort(FJSort o) {
        this.data = o.data.clone();
        this.lo = 0;
        this.hi = this.data.length;
    }

    public FJSort(int[] array, int lo, int hi) {
        this.data = array;
        this.lo = lo;
        this.hi = hi;
    }

    void swap(int i, int j)
    {
        int temp = data[i];
        data[i] = data[j];
        data[j] = temp;
    }

    int mypartition()
    {
        int v = data[hi - 1];
        int i = lo;
        for(int j = hi - 1; j > i;)
        {
            if(data[j] <= v)
            {
                swap(i, j);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                j--;
            }
        }
        if(data[i] < v)
        {
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    int partition()
    {
        int v = data[hi - 1];
        int i = lo;
        for(int j = lo; j < hi - 1; )
        {
            if(data[j] <= v)
            {
                swap(i, j);
                i++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        swap(i, hi - 1);
        return i;
    }

    public void sort()
    {
        Arrays.sort(data, lo, hi);
    }

    public boolean sorted()
    {
        for(int i = lo; i + 1 < hi; i++)
        {
            if(data[i] > data[i+1])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void compute() {
        if (hi - lo < threshold)
            sort();
        else {
            int midpoint = mypartition(); //change to mypartition() is slow
            FJSort left = new FJSort(data, lo, midpoint);
            FJSort right = new FJSort(data, midpoint, hi);
            invokeAll(left, right);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long startTime;
        long endTime;

        FJSort p = new FJSort(1000 * 1000 * 30);
        FJSort p1 =  new FJSort(p);

        {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            p.sort();
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("sorted: " + p.sorted());
            System.out.println("total time: " + (endTime - startTime));
        }

        {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ForkJoinPool fjPool = new ForkJoinPool(1);
            fjPool.invoke(p1);
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("sorted: " + p1.sorted());
            System.out.println("total time: " + (endTime - startTime));
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely because the overhead of using threads is high enough to knock out any parallelization gains.

Comment: The problem is that when using ForkJoin, standard partition() is much faster than mypartition(). This should not relate with overhead of using threads.

Comment: Problem 1 is that you are using invokeAll(left, right). This should be left.fork, right.compute. left.join. Invoke waits for the other computations to complete before moving forward, a significant slowdown. Take a look at the parallel sort in Java8. Join itself doesn't work well so a CountedCompleter is a better choice.

Comment: @edharned, I am not quite understand. I don't think it's a slowdown. In ForkJoin, subtask is processed first, and there is no thread waiting for subtask to be finished because thread can steal other thread's tasks.

Comment: You're hoping stealing will run tasks but that's not the problem. You're forcing one thread to wait for two others to complete when that thread could be working itself. There is no guarantee what thread will be computing your work at any given time. In any case, the invoke() puts tasks into a submission queue, not a work-thread queue. For Java7 there is only one submission queue and you are hoping there are enough free threads to pull tasks out of the submission queue. That isn't always the case as work threads need to finish a request before looking in the submission queue.

Comment: @edharned, you're right. After read the source code of CountedCompleter, I got your point.